# How do I find which brick has a file on glusterFS

Tags: file, location, storage, glusterfs

I have 6 storages(storage1:/data, storage2:/data, ... , storage6:/data) and I've made a clusterdata (using this command "gluster volume create ...").

I mounted the clusterdata in a client and I made a file in it, for example salmple.txt

Does Glusterfs provide any thing to understand which stroage has the sample.txt?
By looking at files in storage1:/data ... storage6:/data I can find which one hast it, but I think that GlusterFS should provide something for that, I would appreciate if anyone who know could help me.

Answer (score 1):

gluster hashes the file into one of the bricks using Elastic hash algorithm.

I think it hash based on the name of the file, for example if you have file sample.txt , delete it again and if you create it back it will get stored in the SAME brick.

As such, gluster does not expose where the file will be hashed. It just hashes the file to specific location by storing directly. (maybe by digging the code , you should be able to figure out, where possibly it gets stored).

Additionally:
There are many different varieties of volume, for example, you can say one brick is local brick, and always have one copy of the file in that local brick, means one copy always gets hashed there.

<< GlusterFS should provide something for that,

not necessarily,  you just access the file from mount location..should not worry about which brick it is stored..so GLUSTER need not provide any mechanism for knowing the detail.

For example if one of the brick is down, hash change. You can also add/remove more bricks...all this is dynamic in nature.

Comment: Thank you kumar. The thing is that I want to run some web servers on gluster. the best way to serve a file for a customer is that a web server on the brick which has the file responds to the customer, not at the mount point. if I reply from mount point it will make an overhead on the system to transfer data from brick to mount point. so I need to know which brick has the file to prevent this overhead.

Comment: @FariborzMafakheri I think there is some misunderstanding here..When a client looks for a file at mount point all it does is hash the FILENAME -> get the file from that location. It WILL NOT look at multiple location to figure out the location. ( on a typical scenario) ..Please note there is NO OVERHEAD to transfer data from brick to mount point. ALL you do is just access the data from mount point. if the brick is DOWN, you wont be able to access the file (as you are directly accessing a network resource(file here)).

Comment: If at all you want a local copy, then you carry out the copy of the file from mount point to local point...but as long as you are accessing the file from mount point, you are using network to access the file.

Comment: Thank you kumar :) so would you think that is there any solution for my problem? or any other better distributed file system?